# VST plugin : using FFT on audio input buffer with arbitrary size, how?

Tags: c#, plugins, fft, vst

I'm getting interested in programming a VST plugin, and I have a basic knowledge of audio dsp's and FFT's.

I'd like to use VST.Net, and I'm wondering how to implement an FFT-based effect.
The process-code looks like

```
public override void Process(VstAudioBuffer[] inChannels, VstAudioBuffer[] outChannels)
```

If I'm correct, normally the FFT would be applied on the input, some processing would be done on the FFT'd data, and then an inverse-FFT would create the processed soundbuffer.

But since the FFT works on a specified buffersize that will most probably be different then the (arbitrary) amount of input/output-samples, how would you handle this ?

Answer (score 4):

FFT requires that your buffer size is a power of two, but to get around this you should just implement an internal buffer and work with that instead.  So for instance:

```
// MyNiftyPlugin.h
#define MY_NUM_CHANNELS 2
#define MY_FFT_BUFFER_SIZE 1024

class MyNiftyPlugin : public AudioEffectX {
  // ... stuff ...
  private:
    float internalBuffer[MY_NUM_CHANNELS][MY_FFT_BUFFER_SIZE];
    long internalBufferIndex;
};
```

And then in your process loop:

```
// MyNiftyPlugin.cpp
void process(float **input, float **output, long sampleFrames) {
  for(int frame = 0; frame < sampleFrames; ++frame) {
    for(int channel = 0; channel < MY_NUM_CHANNELS; ++channel) {
      internalBuffer[channel][internalBufferIndex] = inputs[channel][frame];
    }
    if(++internalBufferIndex > MY_FFT_BUFFER_SIZE) {
      doFftStuff(...);
      internalBufferIndex = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

This will impose a bit of latency in your plugin, but the performance boost you can achieve by knowing the buffer size for FFT during compile time makes it worthwhile.

Also, this is a good workaround for hosts like FL Studio (aka "Fruity Loops") which are known to call process() with different blocksizes every time.

Comment: Bah, I just noticed that you're working in C#, but I gave you C++ example code.  But whatever, the algorithm is pretty simple here and should give you a general idea as to what I mean.

Comment: Shouldn't  `internalBufferIndex` be incremented?

Comment: I think the `if` block needs to be inside the `for` loop